# 404 when trying to access REST Service with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple ASP.NET Web API 2 project setup the has just one controller. The controller is as follows:

```
public class ServiceCodesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/servicecodes
    public List<ServiceCode> Get()
    {
        ServiceCodeRepository _repo = new ServiceCodeRepository();
        return _repo.ServiceCodes().ToList();
    }
}
```

Using `http://localhost:52491/api/ServiceCodes`, I am able to see the results in the browser.

In my angular app however, I am getting a 404 error when trying to access the same url.

```
  app.controller('ServiceCodes', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.serviceCodes = [];

        $http.get('http://localhost:52491/api/ServiceCodes').
              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.serviceCodes = data;
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log(status + " sent "+ data);
              });  
  });
```

angular app is running within node on :8000

Comment: It could be a cross domain issue.

Comment: @Chandermani - It was a cross domain issue. Please change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out and confirm by @Scott this was a cross domain issue. Which requires setting up either `JSONP` or `CORS` on the server side. Or run the app and api on the same port.

Comment: Ended up setting up CORS. Followed this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api